# Unable to save data in SD Card Directory

Tags: android

I have write a code to find if SD card path if available which is like this

```
File[] paths = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);

    if (paths.length > 1) {
        if (paths[1] != null) {
            root = paths[1].getAbsolutePath();
           // for sd card     
        } else {
            root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();    
        }
    } else {
        root = paths[0].getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

I am saving my data in path "/storage/4130-1912/Android/data/com.enable/files" but I wanted to save data outside Android folder. 
I have also tried to make an directory outside the Android folder.But unable to make it.I am testing in Lave phone with version Marhmallow

Comment: just give ur path you want and dont forget the runtime and manifest permissions

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Marshmallow, you should be requesting runtime permissions (more details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)). Despite that, you may add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for external storage access. You can find more information on how to [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files).

You can access the external storage path like this: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()`. If you are getting `FileNotFoundException`, it's probably because you didn't add an additional "/" before your file. Example:

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + 
 "/your_file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am saving my data in path "/storage/4130-1912/Android/data/com.enable/files"

Ok. Go ahead. You will succeed.

> but I wanted to save data outside Android folder.

Well that is not possible anymore on modern Android systems.

Even inside the Android folder you can only write to mentioned private directory for your app.

If you want to write to the whole micro SD card then use the storage access framework.

Answer (score 0):

**This will help you**

As miguelarc said:

> As you are using Marshmallow, you should be requesting runtime
>   permissions (more details here). Despite that, you may add the
>   `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for external
>   storage access.

```
  File   f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getPackageName() + "/yourdir");
                if (f.mkdirs() || f.isDirectory())
                    Log.e("path",f.getPath());
                    //do what you want
            }
```